# The description for Event ID 256 from source DPTF cannot be found. ERROR FUNC: EsifEventProcess FILE: esif_uf_event.c Invalid event source received

Tags: windows-10, laptop, bsod, battery

I have `Alienware 17 R2` laptop, OS is `Windows 10`. I started getting a lot of these errors in `Event Viewer`.

[image]

> The description for Event ID 256 from source DPTF cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> Intel(R) Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework
> ESIF(8.0.10100.71) TYPE: ERROR FUNC: EsifEventProcess FILE: esif_uf_event.c LINE: 201

Invalid event source received

Today I also got BSOD...
**As I understand DPTF (Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework) is related to a laptop battery management, how big an issue this is, or this is unlikely to be related to BSOD?**

Answer (score 0):

In the two threads below the problem was solved, and they might apply to your case.

The thread
[Intel Dynamic platform and thermal framework error computer shutting down](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f3964e2b-84e6-4456-8963-4b30fb75407a/intel-dynamic-platform-and-thermal-framework-error-computer-shutting-down?forum=win10itprogeneral),
which does not seem like fitting your problem, the cause was a bad battery
that needed replacement.

In the thread [DPTF error event id 256](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/DPTF-error-event-id-256/td-p/5801281)
the problem was with system services not being started correctly.
This setting was recommended:

```
Connected Devices Platform Service -> Automatic
Connected Devices Platform User Service_xyz -> Automatic
Network Connection Broker -> Manual
```

If the Windows version does not allow changing service startup attribute, do
[To Start, Stop, and Disable Services in Registry Editor](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/2495-services-start-disable.html#option4) .